# List[Future[A]] => Future[(List[A], List[Throwable])] the most correct solution

Tags: list, scala, future

I have solution:

```
def foo[A](futures: List[Future[A]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[(List[A], List[Throwable])] =
  futures.foldLeft(Future.successful(List.empty[A] -> List.empty[Throwable] )) ( (acc, el) =>
    acc.flatMap { case (oks, errs) =>
      el.map(
        ok =>
          (ok :: oks, errs)
      ).recover {
        case NonFatal(e) =>
          (oks, e :: errs)
      }
    }
  ).map(f => (f._1.reverse, f._2.reverse))
```

Is there any problem, or is there a more correct solution

Updated.

@stefanobaghino (`destructuring tuples to name the fields` comment)

@stefanobaghino `foldRigth` vs `foldLeft` + `reverse` (result contains the same number of elements, so there is no difference in performance)

Comment: Whether it's _correct_ or not is not for us to decide, it depends on what `foo` is supposed to do. You might want to expand on what would be _correct_ and what would not be correct according to do what you want `foo` to achieve. That would help people answer your question so that it's relevant to you.

Comment: The only two things I would probably highlight in a code review would be to use a collection with `O(1)` append so that you can skip the reversal (but that would only relevant if you expect the size of `futures` to grow and become a bottleneck), as well as using destructuring tuples to name the fields, instead of using accessors (but that's just my taste, it's probably advisable to follow the style guide of the codebase you are working in). https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/lU57Q8yHQrWFtFQmZVmcJA/15

Comment: @stefanobaghino If we must have `Future[(List[A], List[Throwable])]` as the result, perhaps there will be no particular performance benefit. At least it's hard for me to estimate the difference. In any case, a correct remark. thanks

Comment: @stefanobaghino The task consists only in the function List[Future[A]]) => Future[(List[A], List[Throwable])] without any context. As a result, I would like to get a working function in the "scala way style". Let 's assume that there is a task "code review".

Comment: @stefanobaghino `destructuring tuples to name the fields` you are right. That's what I do more often. But for some reason there is no habit of doing just that

Comment: I assume you're locked in with your return types then, but also the choice of a `Future` is interesting as well, since given the semantics of your original method, this can never fail.

Comment: @stefanobaghino why this can never fail? foo(List(Future(1/0))

Comment: You collect the failures in the tuple within the future, but the outer future you return can never fail. The result of `foo(List(Future(1/0))` is `Success((List(),List(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)))`.

Comment: @stefanobaghino `recover {case NonFatal(e)` does not recover all exceptions.